# pdo prepared statements with wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I want to execute the following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `gc_users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%anyname%'
```

I tried this without success:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `gc_users` WHERE `name` LIKE :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', "%" . $name . "%");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `gc_users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%:name%'");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

So I ask you if it is possible to use the % wildcard with prepared statements.

/edit

Thank you. Its working with `bindValue`:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `gc_users` WHERE `name` LIKE :name");
$stmt->bindValue(':name', '%' . $name . '%');
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: As for your first attempt - change `bindParam` to `bindValue` and turn [error reporting for PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: [As an alternative to the given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593020/3536236) you can also use the [MySQL CONCAT function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It can work with bind param too in following way:

```
$name = "%$name%";
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `gc_users` WHERE `name` like :name");
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted but please note this solution also works. :)

Comment: I guess it has been downvoted because if your `$name` contains a wildcard itself, it is not escaped.

Comment: I waste my time with have no charset=utf8 in the DSN, I search with Thai character.

Comment: Are the backticks required?

Comment: Proper solution is to use `CONCAT`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277113/5444623

Answer (score 1):

This could be an alternative:

```
$className = '%' . $this->className . '%';
$query->bind_param('s', $className);
```