# How can I with mysqli make a query with LIKE and get all results?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-like

This is my code but it dosn't work:

```
$param = "%{$_POST['user']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$username);
$stmt->fetch();
```

This code it doesn't seem to work. I have searched it a lot.
Also it may return more than 1 row.
So how can I get all the results even if it returns more than 1 row?

Comment: Please define "does not work" - PHP error? MySQL error? No error but 0 results?

Comment: I want to loop through all results. How can i do this?
When i say doesn't work. It returns nothing...

Comment: there is no return operator in this code. **How it is supposed to return anything?**

Comment: Implementation of a query with zero or more LIKE comparisons (dynamically determined): [Build SELECT query with dynamic number of LIKE conditions as a mysqli prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51010509/2943403)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here's how you properly fetch the result

```
$param = "%{$_POST['user']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Note that starting from PHP 8.2 (with a [fallback replacement for 8.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76934685/285587)) a shorter code can be used

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?";
$result = $db->execute_query($sql, ["%{$_POST['user']}%"]);
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

or, if you prefer the old `fetch` and `bind_result` syntax, you can also do:

```
$param = "%{$_POST['user']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id,$username);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "Id: {$id}, Username: {$username}";
}
```

I got the answer directly from the manual [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) and [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).

Comment: In defense of the OP, neither manual page makes any mention of the LIKE comparison "function"

Answer (score 52):

From comments it is found that LIKE wildcard characters (`_`and `%`) are not escaped by default on Paramaterised queries and so can cause unexpected results.

Therefore when using "LIKE" statements, use this ['negative lookahead'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead) Regex to ensure these characters are escaped :

```
$param = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\)([%_])/', '\\\$1',$param);
```

---

As an alternative to the given answer above you can also use the MySQL [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function thus:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();
```

PDO named placeholder version:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE CONCAT('%',:var,'%') ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", ['var'=>$param]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Which means you do not need to edit your `$param` value but does make for slightly longer queries.

---

Comment: Hi is concat safe from sql injection? I'm asking because it has quotes. Thanks

Comment: @mikevorisis Yes, it's safe because the query is still parameterised (*using `?`*) . the quotes are because MySQL is CONCATenating three strings.

Comment: I upvoted this because I'm pretty sure you can't do 'begins with' or 'ends with' using the accepted answer (as in, you need to use `CONCAT`).

Comment: @MikeVorisis, `CONCAT` in prepared statements *are safe* from injection, but you should be cautious while using `LIKE` clause in prepared statements.  Consider this: `$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT `customer` as `suggestion` WHERE `customername` LIKE CONCAT('cust_', ?, '%');");` and then `$key='J%';` (Or even `$key='';`), `$stmt->bind_param('s', $key);`. Now `$stmt->execute();` will return *ALL records*. So, when dealing with Prepared statements having 'LIKE' clause, you still need to handle `_` and `%` in proper way. Even if using prepared statements, escaping like `$key='J\%';` is needed.

Comment: @mikevorisis Though I think you are probably aware of this and have already taken steps to handle such queries properly, I thought it'd be important to share as it may help others reading this too.

Comment: `$param = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\)([%_])/g', '\\\$1',$param);` cannot have the `/g` in there. `preg_replace` does not need the global modifier. It's there implicitly (unless you set the 'limit' argument).

Comment: @starshine531 thanks - such an old question/answer I'd missed that and simply copy/pasted from my raw Regex tool. `:-D`

Comment: php.net/addcslashes is a much simpler alternative to that bushy regexp

Comment: exactly without using Concat function I was facing a weird issue in query

Comment: it is better to avoid the `CONCAT` function let's suppose we do have a `query` in which we have used the `CONCAT` function which found out to grab `1000` data from the `database` it means that this function `CONCAT` recalled `1000` times

Comment: `$param = addcslashes($param, '%_');`