# I need to search field value in LIKE pattern of sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-like

My table looks like this

```
Id  | name   
---------------
1   |  clinker
2   |  gypsum
```

Now I need to prepare a search based on the 'name' field.
here is the select statement

```
select * from table where name like '%$keyword%'
```

Now, suppose the keyword is '**clinker 1**', and I want first row of my table as result set.
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `select * from table where name like '%$keyword%' OR '$keyword' LIKE CONCAT(name,'%')`

Comment: that's no clear, how can you match the row with ID 1 if the keyword is "clinker 1"??

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)

Comment: that 1 in keyword is not Id, it can be any thing like 'clinker a' or ' 3 clinker' or '_ clinker _'

Comment: There is no easy way to accomplish what you want using the MySQL `LIKE` operator.  I have seen this question asked before on Stack Overflow though I cannot remember where.

Comment: Thanks Hanno Binder. I have got the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not quite sure about MySQL, but `LIKE` should work with *any* character expression on either or both sides. That includes both columns and literals. Hence, the `LIKE` can be used the other way around to find the inverse matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR '$keyword' LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to split the `$keyword` and expand your query to match any word in the `$keyword` list:

```
$keywordList = explode(' ', $keyword);
$sql = 'select * from table where ';
while (!empty($keywordList)) {
    $likeKeyword = array_shift($keywordList);
    $sql .= "keyword like '%{$likeKeyword}%'";
    if (!empty($keywordList))
        $sql .= " or ";
}
//...run your query here
```

So if the $keyword is `clinker 1`, the resulting query would be:

```
select * from table where keyword like '%clinker%' or keyword like '%1%'
```