# Want to use LIKE clause

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

I have written a query which gets the node title according to 'term ID' for a 'portfolio' content type.Now I want to get the 'node title' according to the character that means I want to use 'LIKE' clause on the following query.If user enter "a" or "A" then all the node tile from these characters should be fetch.

```
<?php
$nodes = array();
$select = db_query("SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created
                    FROM {node} node
                    WHERE node.status = '1'
                         AND node.type = 'portfolio'
                         AND node.nid IN  (SELECT tn.nid AS nid
                                           FROM {taxonomy_index} tn
                                           WHERE tn.tid = '1')
                    ORDER BY node_created");
    foreach ($select as $nodes) {  
       print $nodes->node_title;
   }
?>
```

Comment: I've edited your code and removed all this unnecessary parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql should be something like

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created
    FROM {node} node
        WHERE node.status = '1'
            AND node.type = 'portfolio'
            AND node.nid IN  
            (
                SELECT tn.nid AS nid
                FROM {taxonomy_index} tn
                WHERE tn.tid = '1'
            )
            AND upper(node.title) like '%<whatever>%'
            ORDER BY node_created
```

You might find more information with the following links
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112530/how-to-use-like-condition-in-db-select-query
Deals with using the API provided by drupal for writing queries instead of the raw sql like this case

[php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)
How to use prepared statements with LIKE (if you don't use the functions provided by drupal to do the work)