# Not able to get desired result in SELECT

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to display search result based on user query. My issue is that I'm not getting all other similar search results (only the exact results are showing). Is it the right method I'm implementing from security point of view? Thanks in advance.

```
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD_HOST','');
define('DATABASE','test');

if(defined('HOST') && defined('USER') && defined('PASSWORD_HOST') && defined('DATABASE')){
    $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD_HOST, DATABASE);


}else{
    die(connection_failed.mysqli_connection_error());
}
```

Here is HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <h4>Search By</h4>
            <input type="text" name="delName"/>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">search</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $delName = "%{$_POST['delName']}%";

    $stmt =$conn->prepare("SELECT id, delName, medName, contact1, contact2, address, pin, creditLimitDealer FROM dealerentrytable WHERE delName LIKE ?");

   $stmt->bind_param("s", $delName); 
   $stmt->execute(); 
   $stmt->bind_result($id, $delName, $medName, $contact1, $contact2,$address,$pin,$creditLimitDealer);

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {

     echo "<table>";
     echo "<tr><td>ID: $id</td>";
     echo "<td>delName: $delName</td>";
      echo "<td>medName: $medName</td>";
       echo "<td>contact1: $contact1</td>";
        echo "<td>contact2: $contact2</td>";
         echo "<td>address: $address</td>";
          echo "<td>pin: $pin</td>";
           echo "<td>creditLimitDealer: $creditLimitDealer</td></tr>";
     echo "</table>";




    }

     $stmt->close();

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you want to search for `$delName` with wildcards, you need it to be `"%".$delName."%"`, or you can concat the wildcards in SQL, with `CONCAT('%', ?, '%')` - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: And check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like

Comment: now it is showing the full table data...! don't know what is wrong..

Comment: You need to explain a bit better, with examples, what exactly are the results you want? What is the content of the database? Read the manual on `LIKE` in MySQL and it might clarify what that does.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.. anyway is it the right method from security point of view?

Comment: You're using prepared statements, so you're covered against SQL-injection.