# MariaDB statement not compatible with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, backend

Backend is not my strongest background and I'm having troubles executing my php scripts while migrating from MySQL to MariaDB (a must for our server provider).
Here is the function I have in my php script that is working with MySQL 5.6 and it's not working with MariaDB (10.1.22-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server):

```
public function getPostByName($postName) {
        $returnValue = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_description LIKE ?";
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if (!$statement)
            throw new Exception($statement->error);

        $postName = "%".$postName."%";
        $statement->bind_param("s", $postName);
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($returnValue, $row);
        }
        return $returnValue;
}
```

I have already try most of the options out there but none of them worked (one example: [php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)). Any suggestion?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error... at all! nothing..

Comment: `print_r($result)` and let us know what is o/p

Comment: still nothing...

Comment: Presumably it works if you type the query directly into the Maria DB console?

Comment: right, it works if I type: 
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_description LIKE "%birthday%"..

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
public function getPostByName($postName){

    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_description LIKE '%".$postName."%'";
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

    if($result != nill && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            array_push($returnValue, $row);
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: so if postName is `Steve';delete from posts;--` would it hurt you?

Comment: That's called "sql injection"; it is nasty.

Comment: `$result != nill` should be `$result === false`.