# sentence WHERE with a field concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I currently have this query.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(`codeDoc`, '-', `prefixDoc`) AS `docId`,
    `descriptionDoc`,
    `statusDoc`
    FROM
    `BD`.`Table`
    WHERE (
       ...
    )
```

that query expects a request GET with a parameter called `searchParam`, I try this.

```
$searchParam = $_GET['searchParam'];
WHERE (
   `docId` LIKE '%".$searchParam."%'"
)
```

But it does not work like i was expected, and i undertand because `docId` is not a field in my table, it only is an alias (`AS docId`).

The question is how to achieve that ?

Comment: you can repeat the concat, `where CONCAT(`codeDoc`, '-', `prefixDoc`) = $your_param`

Comment: Your variable is missing it's `$` and it won't replace to its value while being held inside single quotes Instead: `"WHERE docid LIKE '%".$searchParam."%'"` BUT don't do that either as you are wide open for a SQL injection attack. Like.. .scary wide open. Instead [check out this very similar question for a better way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like) using prepared statements with [`mysqli::bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: @JNevill sorry, I copy and paste wrong, but that is not the error

Comment: This should still 100% be rewritten to parameterize your query using `mysqli::bind_param`. If your `searchparam` from your user comes through as `%'); DROP TABLE BD.Table; --` you are sunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the aliased expressions/fields in `WHERE` clause. Use the expression directly instead. Do the following:

```
$searchParam = $_GET['searchParam'];
WHERE (
   CONCAT(`codeDoc`, '-', `prefixDoc`) LIKE '%$searchParam%'
)
```

**SideNote:** [You should switch to Prepared statements, to prevent SQL injection related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2469308).