# php mysql prepared statement LIKE is not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am aware of this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like). However, my prepared statement is still not working.

Here's the array called `$parameterized`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "1234567"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "1234567"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "%36.5 (u.s. 6.5)%"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "%37 (u.s. 7)%"
}
```

Here's my prepared query called `$query`:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT products.*, prices.max_price, prices.min_price, prices.compare_at_price, collects.position 
    FROM products 
    INNER JOIN collects 
    ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
    AND collects.collection_id = %d  
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT variants.product_id, MAX(variants.price) AS max_price, MIN(variants.price) AS min_price, MAX(variants.compare_at_price) AS compare_at_price 
      FROM variants 
      INNER JOIN collects 
      ON variants.product_id = collects.product_id 
      WHERE collects.collection_id = %d AND (variants.option1 LIKE ? OR variants.option1 LIKE ?) 
      GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY NULL
      ) prices ON products.product_id = prices.product_id 
    ORDER BY collects.position ASC LIMIT 0,12
```

And here's the prepared statement of that prepared query when I execute `$productsQuery = $wpdb->prepare($query, $parameterized)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.*, prices.max_price, prices.min_price, prices.compare_at_price, collects.position 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN collects 
ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND collects.collection_id = 1234567  
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT variants.product_id, MAX(variants.price) AS max_price, MIN(variants.price) AS min_price, MAX(variants.compare_at_price) AS compare_at_price 
  FROM variants 
  INNER JOIN collects 
  ON variants.product_id = collects.product_id 
  WHERE collects.collection_id = 1234567 AND (variants.option1 LIKE ? OR variants.option1 LIKE ?) 
  GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY NULL
  ) prices ON products.product_id = prices.product_id 
ORDER BY collects.position ASC LIMIT 0,12
```

Notice here, `WHERE collects.collection_id = 97476673649 AND (variants.option1 LIKE ? OR variants.option1 LIKE ?)`  where `?` the question marks are and how they are not getting replaced with `"%36.5 (u.s. 6.5)%"` or `"%37 (u.s. 7)%"`.

Is there something wrong with my `$parameterized` array? Are my LIKE arguments in that array incorrect? Or is the symbol `?` in my SQL string -- `variants.option1 LIKE ? OR variants.option1 LIKE ?` -- invalid?

Comment: I don't think `$wpdb->prepare` uses `?` at all. If you need a placeholder for a string, use `%s`.

Comment: @Aioros you are correct! All I had to do was change the `?` for `%s`.

Comment: @robskrob I added "in Wordpress" to the title in an edit. That will help with (Google) searches and on Stack Overflow also.