# SQL in php, make partial search using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make SQL in php to return all the entries that matches a keyword that is entered by the user (from search bar). 
I want to return all the entries that their name "partial" matches with the keyword. 
I want at least to match the keyword, if an entry name in database before has space and after maybe another letter/space.
For example I have three entries with names "Milk", "Semi skimmed Milk" and "Full Milk 2". If the keyword is "Milk" or "milk" or "MiLK", I want to get all these three entries. 
The only case I am thinking it might be the problem is case sensitive.
I tried with a keyword that exists exactly in database, but my app (on android) stops .

Based on user3783243 answer.

PHP FILE

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $keyword);
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row["name"] . ",";
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["name"] . ",";
    }
} else {
    echo "0";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you actually doing a POST somewhere in your android code?

Comment: @user3783243 can you explain more? you mean to have this statement before? bind_param('keyword', ?);. i used post method in another case and it gets the value.

Comment: @JonAte Don't link to another question.  Include _your code_ in the body of the question.

Comment: `$keyword = "%{$_POST['keyword']}%"; $pdoStmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);` or `$pdoStmt->bindParam(1, $keyword,PDO::PARAM_STR);` when using SQL `name LIKE ?`

Comment: or `$mysli_stmt->bind_param('s', $keyword)`

Comment: pdo: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone and in query after LIKE i must have a "?"

Comment: @JonAte Yes, positional `LIKE ?` (PDO/mysqli) or named `LIKE :keyword` (PDO only)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query. It should work. Check that you are actually doing a request from your application to the server like @PatrickQ suggests.

Comment: @TahaPaksu it's working but it's not preventing sql injection anyways. I also read that MySQL is case insensitive? so there will be no problem

Comment: You asked "why does my android app crash?", not "how can I prevent SQL injection inside this?", so I'm answering your question. People are all focused on that (except the copy paste commenters)

Comment: @TahaPaksu Updated now the question based of user3783243 answer. Which it stills crash my app

Comment: You forgot to execute the statement. before get_result. `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: @TahaPaksu The query is invalid since it is a string. `SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', Milk, '%')` won't execute unless `milk` is a column. Even the `concat` function requires quotes. A driver with bound values adds the quotes, and escapes as needed.

Comment: @user3783243 the current question (I don't know if it was wrong before) is structured correctly. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593020/916000 the bound parameter will be inserted surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @TahaPaksu Yes, there have been 6 revisions. The current version is the code I wrote (see answer below). I forgot the `execute()` which you pointed out. The comments are from revisions 1-4.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', ?, '%')";
```

and then `$keyword` should be bound with whatever syntax the driver you are using supports.

As is your query would have been:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', Milk, '%')
```

and you wanted `Milk` to be a string so it needed to be quoted. As is `mysql` would have thought that was a column.

Alternatively you could do:

```
$keyword = '%' . $_POST['keyword'] . '%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ?";
```

that is the same and still requires the binding though.

The binding also takes away the SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and/or https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29

Per update.. replace:

```
$keyword =$_POST['keyword']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

with:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $keyword);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
if(empty($conn->errno) && !empty($res)) { 
     while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row["name"] . ",";
     }
} else {
     echo '0';
     //print_r($conn->errno);
}
$conn->close();
```

...

also remove

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["name"] . ",";
    }
} else {
    echo "0";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: $keyword = '%' . $_POST['keyword'] . '%'; stmt->bind_param("s",$keyword)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ?"; but it my app still stops.

Comment: What is `stmt`? You should really use error reporting. Cut the java/android out of the question and just get the PHP working first. Inside the getting the PHP working get the `mysqli` working. These all require different error reporting.

Comment: I didn't understood what I have to do with the binding. I use mysqli

Comment: 1. Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php for error reporting. 2. Prepare your query first, 3. bind 4. execute 5. fetch... Without the actual PHP execution there's no way for us to know how you run the query.

Comment: I tried $keyword =$_POST['keyword']; $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%)"; and it's working but how I can make that bind? Can I add this line between these two statements? $keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($keyword);

Comment: `mysql_` wont work with `mysqli`. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for full documentation on how to prepare, bind, and execute. If you update the question with your code that executes the query we can help with that

Comment: It doesn't work.It makes my app crash. Are you sure I should only replace these 3 lines?. I think I should also change if/else

Comment: @JonAte Yes, only 1 fetch. See update. Also your app wasn't crashing previously? Really you should narrow down the issue. Stop using the app and confirm it is the PHP failing.

Comment: I don't know why but it still stops. I think it's concat. I am using a local server. Did you test this on a small database?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can convert the input in search bar to either upper or lower case by default then apply query in db like

For Upper case:

```
$keyword =strtoupper($_POST['keyword']); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE upper(name) LIKE '%$keyword%)";
```

Or for lower case:

```
$keyword =strtolower($_POST['keyword']); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%$keyword%)";
```

Comment: By applying this you can equalizing the case of query with the db entry like if someone write "MilK" in search box, strtoupper will convert it as "MILK" and store it in variable $keyword, then you have applied query upper(name) in db by which entries like milk,miLK,Milk etc will be converted in "MILK" and you will get a match a perfect one.