# PHP /MYSQL Search Form Displaying Empty Results

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, search

Please Guys what must be wrong with this my code, I have tried to fetch the search data from my Database as follows

Students DATA As follow

Reg Number: Full Name: Faculty: Program: Level: Group.

on the HTML Search Page

```
<html> 
<h2> Enter your matric number to connect to others studying your course </h2>
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
<b> ReG </b><input type="text" Name="find">
<input type="submit"  value="Submit" />

</form>
</html>
```

PHP SIDE

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Student Full Name</th>
<th> Faculty</th>
<th> Program</th>
<th> Entry Year</th>
<th> Study Group</th>
<th> Group Members Contact</th>
<th> Group Leader Contacts</th>
</tr>



<?php 

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "student");
// Check connection
if($conn=== false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 $q = $_POST['find'];


if ($q == "")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM study_circle WHERE matric LIKE $q ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result)
 {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {





        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td>";

    echo  $row['full_name'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['faculty'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['program'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['entry_year'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['study_group'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['group_members'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo  $row['group_leader'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";
    echo  "<br/>";




    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Each time I try it it's bringing Empty results even though I have populated the database

Right now it's on my Localhost system, please anyone good person to help, am just new to Programming. I will be happy to fix this

Comment: Maybe, $q is a string.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and see what it displays. if it displays `null` or `[]` (empty array), there's something wrong with your SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is misinterpreting what a `false` value means here:

```
if ($result)
{
    //...
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

A `false` value in `$result` doesn't mean the search didn't find anything, it means **the query failed with an error**.  To get the error, use `mysqli_error`:

```
if ($result)
{
    //...
} else {
    echo "There was an error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

In this case the error is *probably* a syntax error in your SQL code because you're directly concatenating user input to SQL code.  This is also called a [SQL injection vulnerability](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  There is some good information to get you started on [correcting that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), including specifically how to use [query parameters with the `LIKE` operator here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like).  At its simplest you will want to use a prepared statement with a query parameter instead of using string interpolation like you do now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding wildcard characters to the start and end of the search string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM study_circle WHERE matric LIKE '%$q%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You willl need to get the rowcount of the search data. That will gurantee if the record is there or not
Eg.

```
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

and then perform if statement with it.

**see code below.**

```
<?php 

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "student");
// Check connection
if($conn=== false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 $q = $_POST['find'];


if ($q == "")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM study_circle WHERE matric LIKE $q ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if( $rowcount ){

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);





        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td>";

    echo  $row['full_name'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['faculty'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['program'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['entry_year'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['study_group'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  $row['group_members'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo  $row['group_leader'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";
    echo  "<br/>";


    exit;
}else{
 echo "0 results";

}
}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```