# i want to fetch data using below query but its not working

Tags: php

```
$query = $_POST["name"];
$mob = $_POST["phone"];
```

is that this query is correct

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM oath WHERE name='%".$query."%' && phone='%".$mob."%'";
```

Comment: Do you want `name LIKE '%...` rather than `=`

Comment: do i use Like operator ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like to see how to do it properly with prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks its working correctly using "LIKE" operator

Comment: What are you using to execute your queries? PDO or MySQLi?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three issues:

- when you use a wildcard `%`, use `LIKE` operator to check whether a specific character string matches a specified pattern
- replace `&&` with `AND` to combine your boolean expressions (MySQL supports `&&` operator, but other database engines don't)
- always use preprared statements

Your statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oath WHERE name LIKE '%".$query."%' AND phone LIKE '%".$mob."%'";
```

Prepared statement:

```
<?php
...
# Input
$name  = $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"]; 
$name  = "%$name%";
$phone = "%$phone%"; 

# Statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oath WHERE name LIKE :name AND phone LIKE :phone";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);

# Execution 
$statement->execute();

# Result
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

...
?>
```

Comment: MySQL supports `&&` ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and

Comment: @Phil Yes, thanks for this note. The question has no database tag, so probably using `AND` will be more appropriate here.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even notice there wasn't a tag but OP most probably is using MySQL. I agree that `AND`, `OR`, etc are more readable but it would be incorrect to say that `&&` is a problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

`name='%".$query."%'` ... `phone='%".$mob."%'"`

here you are mixing `equality comparison` ie `=` with `wild card search` ie `%` which is wrong.

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oath WHERE name LIKE '%".$query."%' AND phone LIKE '%".$mob."%'";
```

and also replace `&&` with `AND`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oath WHERE name LIKE '%".$query."%' AND phone LIKE '%".$mob."%'";
```