# highlight multiple keywords in search (PHP)

Tags: php, search

I am using this code to highlight search keywords:

```
<form method="post">  
    <input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["keyword"])) echo $_GET["keyword"]; ?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />  
</form>  

<?php 
if(isset($_GET["keyword"]))  
{  
    $condition = '';  
    $query = explode(" ", $_GET["keyword"]);  
    foreach($query as $text)  {  $condition .= "name LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $text)."%' OR "; }  
    $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);  
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE " . $condition;  
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);  
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
    {  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
            echo ''.$row["name"].'';  
        }  
    }  
    else  {  echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';  }  
}  
?>
```

However, this highlights only one "keyword".

If the user enters more than one keyword, it will narrow down the search but no word is highlighted. How can I highlight more than one word?

Comment: I don't see any highlighting in your posted script.  Appending empty strings to both sides of a variable is ...weird/unnecessary ...who is teaching people to code like this?

Comment: If you mean "how to search for multiple keywords?" There are probably tens of duplicates for you to find on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)

Comment: I want to bold the keyword loop, 
<b>iphone</b> apple <b>S7</b>

Comment: example : http://s2.picofile.com/file/8371867292/oo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple search with like  should use regexp

For example

```
SELECT * from products where name REGEXP 'apple|table';
```

Comment: I want every word found in the search results
That bold word
If the word is found, it will be bold in the search results

http://s3.picofile.com/file/8371886668/shot.jpg

Comment: <bold><?php echo ''.$row["name"].''; ?></bold>

Comment: Which of the following code can make the word bold?
`$highlighted = preg_replace("|($text)|Ui" , "<b>$1</b>" , $row['name'] );` OR `$highlighted = preg_filter('/' . preg_quote($_GET['keyword'], '/') . '/i', '<b>$0</b>', $row['name']);`

Comment: You can make filter with Vuejs or angular.js repeat data and for filter create make custome filter ... I u want just php ,Not in this way.you must retrieve two array and merge all product and filter array ,in filler array have include input values

Comment: I want to highlight the search results with a few keywords found

Comment: I think You can do with js.i think no with PHP .search word in Dom element if found change html of Dom element.all filters generally make with js

Comment: I want to bold the word with this code, example:
http://s5.picofile.com/file/8371911526/bold.jpg