# Search records displaying the HTML tags

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a search where the user can search for anything and will display the output on the screen.

I am getting my output but there is some issue with my output. It's also displaying the HTML code. For example I searched `Ackn` then I am getting the output  `Acknowledgement<\/li><\/ul>"`

**Process.php**

```
function search_service($conn){
    $output='';
    $param = "%{$_POST['searchquery']}%";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,heroheading FROM article1 WHERE heroheading LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$heroheading);
    $output ='<ul class="list-unstyled">';
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $output .='<li>'.$heroheading.'</li>';
    }
    $output .='</ul>';
    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode($output); 
}
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search_service').keyup(function(){
   var searchquery =$(this).val();
   if(searchquery!=''){

      $.ajax({
        url:"process.php?action=search_service",
        type: 'post',
        datatype:'json',
        data:{searchquery:searchquery},
        success: function(response) {
         $('#searchList').fadeIn();
         $('#searchList').html(response);
        },
    });
   }

   else{
      $('#searchList').fadeIn();
      $('#searchList').html();

   }
})
});
```

Comment: first run the PHP code and see if it works

Comment: What's the output in network tab?

Comment: Why prepare a query if you don't plan on binding?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like to show how to bind with like.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly, oh!  thanks for sharing this good information.

Comment: @NigelRen, I tried you a link which you shared but it's working only else part. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: You are also outputting a `$conn->connect_error` as a result of possibly failing a `->prepare()` that should be a `$conn->error`

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, as per your last comment. Do I have to use 4 lines in process.php?

Comment: That is where I would put them until you get the bugs out of the script

Comment: And what is the new problem

Comment: I am getting the output with HTML tags. something like https://prnt.sc/pa8k33

Comment: Pretty sure you dont need to `json_encode()` that string. Just pass it back as it is

Comment: @RiggsFolly, What I did, display the output using echo $output; before the json_encode and I am getting the correct output but after calling JSON to display output on the screen then I am getting the issue. As per your last comment Should I remove json_encode()?

Comment: So why did you consider that passing back JSON was necessary? JSON would normally be used to pass data back to Javascript, like `x=1, y=2,z=3` but you are just passing a string of HTML, so its not necessary

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Ok I remove the json_encode() and write echo $output. Now I am getting my output. thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Like in query, you should add % before or after or both to get records.
 Example :

```
$query = 'SELECT id, heroheading FROM article1 WHERE heroheading LIKE "%'.$search_parm.
  '%"';
```

View instruction in [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/)

Comment: I already added in the variable $search_parm

Comment: @questionbank reread what is being said in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

you need to modify your query by adding %SEARCH WORDS%  Like this to find all possible records

$query = 'SELECT id, heroheading FROM article1 WHERE heroheading LIKE "%'.$search_parm.'%"';