# How do I use MYSQL WHERE LIKE with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a table that stores cities

```
id | city         | player 
1  | Miami        | Mark
2  | Miami Beach  | Tiffany
3  | New York     | John
4  | Boston       | Bette
5  | Boston       | Laura
```

I have a query that selects the city according to input

```
$select = $conn->prepare("SELECT player FROM game_table WHERE city LIKE=?");
$select->bind_param("s", $city);
$select->execute();
$select->close();
```

How do I use the query with a prepared statement and select everyone from the same city? Miami should return 2 players. How can I make sure the system recognizes Miami Beach as part of Miami?

Comment: Your query is missing the quotes resulting in a parse error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: I forgot to put them in here they are alright in my codes.. Edited my question.

Comment: @SaturnConjuction I see you figured this out. I updated my answer to remove the equal sign.

Comment: Ok @SaturnConjuction Remove the `=` in this `LIKE=?`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: For some reason it does not work. I receive a MYSQL syntax error.

Comment: @SaturnConjuction Ooops, I left something out because it's been a while since I've used LIKE.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527848/1415724) in another post here on Stack.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner : Thank you very much. You can mark this as duplicate. Sorry for this :-S

Comment: @SaturnConjuction Welcome. I would but I already cast my vote as unclear :( due to the missing quotes earlier.

Comment: Be sure you use '%' prefix/sufix in the search criteria as city LIKE 'Miami' is the same as city = 'Miami'. if you want to find both Miami and Miami Beach yo need to specify city LIKE 'Miami%'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)