# Call to undefined method mysqli::execute_query()

Tags: php, mysqli

This are the files I'm using:

**modeloBd.php**

```
<?php
class modeloBd
{
    private static $server = "127.0.0.1";
    private static $user = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $dbname = "bd";

    protected $conn;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $conexion = new mysqli(self::$server, self::$user, self::$password, self::$dbname);
        if ($conexion->connect_error) {
            die("Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $conexion->connect_error);
        } else {
            $this->conn = $conexion;
        }
    }
}
```

**modeloLogin.php**

```
<?php
require_once "modeloBd.php";

class modeloLogin extends modeloBd
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function existe($ci)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE ci = ? LIMIT 1";
        $result = $this->conn->execute_query($query, [$ci]);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $num;
    }
```

**controladorLogin.php**

```
<?php
require '../Modelo/modeloLogin.php';
require '../Modelo/modeloToken.php';

class controladorLogin
{
    public static function chequear($content)
    {
        $ci = $content['post']['ci'];
        $contrasenia = $content['post']['contrasenia'];
        $l = new modeloLogin();
        if ($l->existe($ci)) {
        //code
        }
    }
}
```

I just needed to make my query work in here:

```
public function existe($ci)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE ci = ? LIMIT 1";
        **$result = $this->conn->execute_query($query, [$ci]);**
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $num;
    }
```

But instead the system gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method **mysqli::execute_query()** in C:\xampp\htdocs\main\Modelo\modeloLogin.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\main\Control\controladorLogin.php(12): modeloLogin->existe('1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\main\Control\superControlador.php(11): controladorLogin::chequear(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\main\Modelo\modeloLogin.php on line 13

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php - note the minimum version number.

Comment: Thank you for asking a very good question providing all required information including the exact code you tried and the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php) for `execute_query` says "(PHP 8 >= 8.2.0)".

It is a [new feature in PHP 8.2](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mysqli_execute_query) which, at the time of writing [is the newest version of PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history).

To use that function you need to upgrade your PHP install. (Note that it is easy to have *different* versions of PHP installed for command line and web server use, so make sure that you upgrade the version associated with your web server).

---

Alternatively you could use the older approach (detailed in the blog post linked above) and call `prepare`, `bind_param`, `execute` and `get_result` in turn.

Answer (score 2):

This inconvenience can be rather easily mitigated by checking the current PHP version and *extending* the `mysqli` class if needed.

You can add a code like this to where your database connection is created

```
$mysqli_class_name = 'mysqli';
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '8.2', '<')) {

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    function mysqli_execute_query(mysqli $mysqli, string $query, ?array $params = null)
    {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        if ($params) {
            $types = str_repeat("s", count($params));
            $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result();
    }    
    
    class my_mysqli extends mysqli {
        public function execute_query(string $query, ?array $params = null)
        {
            return mysqli_execute_query($this, $query, $params);
        }
    }
    $mysqli_class_name = 'my_mysqli';
}
$mysqli = new $mysqli_class_name($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

This code would universally work for any PHP version >= 7.0. In case current PHP version is below 8.2, it will use the extended version of mysqli class, and original class otherwise.

---

Please note that you should **never create a database connection in your models**. This way your code will create hundreds of mysql connections and kill your database server. The database connection should be passed as a constructor parameter instead.

Therefore, `modeloBd` in its current form must be scrapped, while class `modeloLogin` should be made like this:

```
class modeloLogin
{
    protected $conn;
    public function __construct(mysqli $mysqli)
    {
        $this->$conn = $mysqli;
    }

    public function existe($ci)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE ci = ? LIMIT 1";
        $result = $this->conn->execute_query($query, [$ci]);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $num;
    }
}
```