# Does this custom function prevent sql injection?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am building a class to run queries and created this method in order to easily run prepared statements throughout my other classes. My main concern was that I currently do not have any regex validation for a lot of my input. I didn't think this would matter when using prepared statements but I would like to know if my current method is secure enough without adding additional validation like regex.

```
public function runQuery($query, $params = [])
{
    if (empty($params)) {
        return $this->dbConnection->query($query);
    }

    $stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($query);
    if (!$stmt) return;

    $types = "";
    $bindParams = [];

    foreach ($params as $param) {
        $types .= $param[0];
        $bindParams[] = &$param[1];
    }

    array_unshift($bindParams, $stmt, $types);

    call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $bindParams);

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
}
```

And this is a psuedo example of how I am using it:

```
$query = "UPDATE `members` SET `group` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$params = [
    ['i', $newGroup],
    ['i', $userId]
];
$dbConnection->runQuery(query, $params);
```

It works as expected. But I have yet to write testing for this so I am trying to currently figure out if this works securely enough.

Comment: It's secure but redundant. Mysqli *already* has such a function called [execute_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php) and you definitely should use this existing solution instead of that code.

Comment: Also, questions like "is this function all right" are better suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than Stack Overflow proper

Comment: I was under the impression that execute_query() wasn't available 8.2, I'm still on 8. something. Also thank you for pointing me to that forum.

Comment: you can easily add a [temporary substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76934685/285587). Yes, it does almost the same as your own function, but makes your code more consistent with the rest of PHP and eventually you'll be able to remove this code altogether

Comment: Oh that's perfect. I should be able to upgrade to 8.2 in the coming months, waiting on a third party dependency.

Comment: If you want to improve your function, you need to remove things that are bad practice. Never use `empty` unless you really know what you are doing. Don't use `call_user_func_array`; instead use array spread. Use parameter and return types. Do not fallback on `query()` as this is using a different protocol and could give you different results. Do not do `if (!$stmt) return;`. If you have mysqli exception mode enabled, it will throw an exception so this is unneeded.

Comment: To answer your question: this function is not vulnerable to SQL injection because it's never building SQL with variable input. The SQL is provided as a parameter and is unchanged inside the function. SQL happens when you allow variables inside of SQL string, which you never do anywhere in this code.