Use variable PHP in query Select
I am trying to use variable in query Select, but there is error or empty result.
$rank = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "rank");

$resultDown = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 'rank'>$rank ORDER BY 'rank' ASC LIMIT 1");
    while($rowDown = $resultDown->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rank2 = $rowDown["rank"];
    }

Can you help me please? There is some problem in the middle part WHERE 'rank'>$rank, but can not find how its correct.

Are you getting a specific error? But anyway you should not concatenate variables directly into your query like that, it leaves you vulnerable to syntax errors and also to SQL injection attacks. Always use prepared statements and parameters - see the duplicate question (in the blue box above) for details and examples.

Also 'rank' needs to be \rank`` I think (in both places where you've used it in the SQL), since it's a column name, not a literal string. Or you can do it without the backticks, since there's no space in the name or anything like that

while($rowDown = $resultDown->fetch_assoc()) {         $rank2 = $rowDown["rank"];     }...this will only ever get you the last result returned by the query, because $rank2 =...  will overwrite the value of $rank2 every time your code loops over a new record. Why not just use fetch_all(); to get an array of results ready-made, instead of writing a loop? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

P.S. I doubt $table even needs to be a variable in the first place - just hard-code the table name. You're unlikely to change or vary it since you're writing the rest of the query against a specific column names which presumably only exist in that one table. (If you have multiple tables with the same set of columns in them, that's almost certainly a design flaw in your database)

@ADyson - changed ' to ` helped and its working, thank you so much...
Yes, result should be only one, thats correct and variable $table is defined before.

result should be only one...then, again, why are you looping? Just use fetch_assoc() once only, without a loop. But >$rank implies there could be more than one result which is greater than $rank. How do you know that's not going to be possible sometimes?

variable $table is defined before...but what is the point of defining it separately, if it never changes? It just makes your query harder to read. A variable is only useful if you're going to change its value sometimes.

And you still need to change to using prepared statements and parametes, for reliability and security. Don't get into bad habits using your current approach. Whoever taught you to write your queries like that needs an important lesson themselves.

@ADyson result should be only one - its written to find nearest higher - ODER by rank ASC Limit 1

@ADyson - variable $table its because in begining of the file it check what language its written and depend on it will choose correct table in sql.

That sounds like a bad datamodel, you don't change tables because you have different language. An extra column "language" solves this issue in a much cleaner way.

Yeah that's true there should be no need to change table just because of the language. Add a language column to one table and select the data based on  that. It's just a property of the data, not an entirely different entity

@Adyson understand, thank you for advice, will change that. In that way, can you tell me, why is this correct
$resultDown = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM menu_admin WHERE rank>$rank ORDER BY rank ASC LIMIT 1");
but this line
$sql = "UPDATE menu_admin SET name=$name WHERE id=$id";
must be in this way
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";
to work?

Neither is really correct - they both need to be parameterised. But if you mean why the second one fails without the quote marks round $name it's simple - string values need to be quoted, in basic sql syntax, but numbers do not

So whats should be the best kind of correct nation?
$sql = "UPDATE menu_admin SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id";
(if $name is string and $id is integer)

No. None of that matters really. You need to parameterise the queries, as I've said several times already. And then you don't even have to worry about quoting or not quoting. Did you read either of the posts I've linked you to (in the blue box above your question)?

PHP manual? Yes, I did.

Neither of those links point to the php manual. They're at the top of your page, in the blue box. I linked them for a reason, please read them

@ADyson I am trying to rewrite the code to do it correctly, but there is still some mistake. Can you say where please?
db.php
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $dbname);
index.php
$lang = $_SESSION["lang"];
$result = $conn->execute_query("SELECT * FROM homepage WHERE lang=?", [$lang]);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$title = $row["title"];
...
}
there is error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::execute_query() ... on line $result = $conn...

@TomášRejka What version of PHP are you running? As per the documentation the execute_query() function was introduced in PHP 8.2. How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement also mentions this very clearly, and right below that it shows the way you can do it if you have an older version.

Did you read any of that, or try the alternative code?? Or if you didn't read that for some reason, did you try googling the error? I'm not really sure why I'm sitting here just telling you things you can already read for yourself very easily and clearly, contained in links I've already given you to read

There are also plenty of examples in good resources such as https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli, in the PHP documentation itself, and many other places online.

See also existing posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76934191/call-to-undefined-method-mysqliexecute-query, which you'd find in a few seconds by googling the error message. There's really no reason to be stuck on this, as far as I can see.

Yes, I did read it and yes, i was googling the error.

Not sure how you didn't find the relevant information then?? It's very clearly stated, anywhere that you look

@ADyson but I do not want to sound ungreatfull. I was reading links you sended to me and was looking for error, but did not find anything to helped me. Just about 2 minutes ago I found the mistake. But I am very greatfull to you for your help. Thank you

No problem. But I really don't understand how you didn't see it? In How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement it says Starting from PHP 8.2 you can... and then right below it If your PHP version is old, then.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76934191/call-to-undefined-method-mysqliexecute-query (which you find easily by googling the error) says To use that function you need to upgrade your PHP install.

Just about 2 minutes ago I found the mistake...I told you the reason 2 hours ago here
