php code to search single field from php form input and display all rows from mysql db
I found this php code to search multiple fields from php form input in mysql database and display the results in that same form.
The code:
//search
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $info = getData();
        $search_query="SELECT * FROM bike_in WHERE vin LIKE '%$info[1]%'";
    $search_result=mysqli_query($conn, $search_query);
        if($search_result)
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($search_result))
            {
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
                {
                    $vin = $rows['vin'];
                    $motor = $rows['motor'];
                    $battery1 = $rows['battery1'];
                    $battery2 = $rows['battery2'];
                        $model = $rows['model'];
                        $colour = $rows['colour'];
                        $lot = $rows['lot'];
                        $date_in = $rows['date_in'];
                    }
                } else {
                echo("no data are available");
                               }
                } else{
            echo("result error");
                }

} 

when i input a search value, i have to input all 8 fields, but i would like to search only from 1 field (vin), and when i hit the "Search" button, i want it to display all fields related to that "vin".
After insert VIN, clicking the "Search" button asks the user to input "Motor".
This happens until all 8 fields are filled in, even with only "1" as the value. 
This are the results i get from the search.(correct)
I would like to be able to just input "VIN" field only and when i hit "Search" button, all 8 values related to this VIN is displayed.
Thanks PHP Gurus.

There's nothing in the code you posted to show where something makes you fill in "all 8 fields", perhaps that's in the form code. You should edit your post to show the form code too. The code you posted only searches on one field. But, you should read up on "Prepared Statements" instead of just concatenating user-supplied data into queries like that. What does the getData() function do?

Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. any search with a ' in the text (such as don't, or O'Reilly)  would crash your query because SQL would think the ' was terminating the input string after the preceding character.

Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement, How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

For your particular query (using LIKE), you can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/how-can-i-with-mysqli-make-a-query-with-like-and-get-all-results

Short Answer:
Remove "required" attribute from each field.
Explanation
This has nothing to do with PHP, you are correctly searching VIN in PHP. The "This field is required" error is generated by the browser because you added "required" attribute to each field.
You need to remove the required attribute from each field and use backend validation while creating/updating records. If you still like to use client side validation, you will need to use JavaScript.
You can either perform the validation manually or remove HTML form submission entirely and use AJAX to search for VIN #.
Here are two different examples that illustrate the point:
Using JavaScript for Validation
<input type="text" name="vin" id="vin" > <!-- Remove "required" from all fields" -->

<button type="submit" onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="search()">Search</button>

<script>
function add() {
  // Validate all fields here
  let vin = $("#vin").val(); // assuming you use jQuery.
  if (vin == "" || vin == null) {
    // display error
    window.event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  // repeat for all fields
}
</script>

Using AJAX to perform searching
<!-- Replace type="submit" by type="button" in search button -->
<button type="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>

<script>
async function search() {
   // get the vin number
   let res = await fetch("products/getdata?vin=" + vin);
   let data = await res.json();
   motor.value = data.motor;
   // repeat for all fields
}
</script>

