# How do I get a <select> <option> to sort and return a query in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get my   to select, sort and return query from mysql data base but it keeps returning the whole table of information as opposed to the selected info that I am trying to get. I have the HTML and PHP code. Can someone please help me? Whenever I include the " :" on items in the WHERE  field I get a "not defined " error such as  category not defined" etc...
here is the code:

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
  try {
     $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bajan_glasses';
     $db = new PDO($dsn, 'glasses_cms', '8019');

    $sql = 'SELECT id, category, style, color, material, size, price, image,  
  position, caption, visible

            FROM eyeglasses
            WHERE id LIKE id  AND category = category AND style = style AND 
  color = color
             AND material = material AND size = size AND price = price AND 
  image = image AND  position = position
            AND caption = caption AND visible = visible
            ORDER BY id'; 
    // <!--------------------- when ":" is added to the above , the table 
 does not display------------->   

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', '%' . $_GET['id'] . '%');
    // $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $_GET['category'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':style', $_GET['style'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':color', $_GET['color'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':material', $_GET['material'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':size', $_GET['size'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $_GET['price'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':image', $_GET['image'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':position', $_GET['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':caption', $_GET['caption'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':visible', $_GET['visible'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

   //  $stmt->execute('bindParam'); // use://if still getting token error.
     $stmt->execute(); 

     if (isset($errorInfo[2])) {
        $error = $errorInfo[2];
     }
  } catch (Exception $e) {

    $error = $e->getMessage();
   }
  }

 ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>PDO: SELECT Loop</title>
 <link href="../../styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>



<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">




<fieldset>

<p>

<label for="id">id </label>
 <select name="id" id="id">
 <?php

//$material = array('woo' => 'wood');
//$material = array('ace' => 'acetate');
///$material = array('pla' => 'plastic');
//$material = array('ste' => 'steel');



  for ($id =0; $id <=1 ; $id++) { 
  echo "<option>$id</option>";
    };

            ?>         



    </select>




 <label for="category ">category </label>
 <select name="category " id="category ">


     <option> </option>
       <option>men</option>         
        <option>women</option>
        <option>children</option>

   </select>




<label for="style ">style </label>
<select name="style " id="style ">


   <option  selected value="style">style</option>
       <option>aviator</option>         
        <option>rectangular</option>
        <option>round</option>
        <option>square</option>
        <option>vintage</option>
        <option>black</option>


   </select>




 <label for="color ">color </label>
 <select name="color " id="color ">


        <option></option>
        <option>white</option>
        <option>blue</option>
        <option>green</option>
        <option>yellow</option>
        <option>brown</option>
        <option>black</option>
        <option>red</option>
        <option>pink</option>
        <option>pink</option>

    </select>


<label for="material">Material </label>
<select name="material" id="material">
 <?php

//$material = array('woo' => 'wood');
//$material = array('ace' => 'acetate');
///$material = array('pla' => 'plastic');
//$material = array('ste' => 'steel');



  // for ($material = 'wood'+'steel';   $material <= 'plastic'; $material++) 
  { 
  // echo "<option>$material</option>";
   // };

        ?>         

        <option> </option>
        <option>wood</option>
        <option>acetate</option>
        <option>plastic </option>
        <option>steel </option>
     </select>




  <label for="size">size </label>
<select name="size" id="size">
   <?php

  $size = array('sma' => 'small');
  $size = array('med' => 'medium');
  $size = array('lar' => 'large');


        for ($size= 'small'; $size<= 'medium'; $size++) { 
            echo "<option>$size</option>";

       };

        ?>  

        <option> </option>
        <option>small</option>
        <option>medium</option>
        <option>large</option>

    </select>


 <label for="price ">price</label>
 <select name="price " id="price ">


   <option  selected value="price"></option>
       <option>$199</option>            
        <option>rectangular</option>
        <option>$259</option>
        <option>$129</option>
        <option>$111</option>
        <option>$111</option>


 </select>




 <label for="style ">image </label>
 <select name="image " id="image ">


   <option ></option>



   </select>




 <label for="style ">position</label>
 <select name="style " id="style ">


   <option  selected value="position"></option>
       <option>1</option>           
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>



   </select>



 <label for="style ">caption</label>
 <select name="style " id="style ">


   <option  selected value="style"></option>
       <option>Choose from Mens styles...</option>          
        <option>men glasses</option>
        <option>women glasses</option>
        <option> children glasses...</option>



   </select>       




 <label for="visible  ">visible </label>
 <select name="visible  " id="visible  ">



       <option></option>            
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>



   </select>       



<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>

 <?php if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
 $row = $stmt->fetch();
 if ($row) {

    ?>
  <table>
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
    <th>category</th>
    <th>style</th>
    <th>color</th>
    <th>material</th>
    <th>size</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
    <th>position</th>
    <th>caption</th>
     <th>visible</th>

  </tr>
  <?php /******** foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {*********/?>
   <?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['category'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['style'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['color'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['material'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['size'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['image'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['position'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['caption'];?></td>      
      <td><?php echo $row['visible'];?></td>
    </tr>

  <?php } while ($row = $stmt->fetch()); ?> 
</table>
  <?php } else {
    echo '<p>No results found.</p>';
 }}
 }   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Including the "minimal" part.

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons like this will *always* be true:

```
category = category
```

After all, when would anything ever not equal *itself*.  So indeed every record in the table will always match those conditions.

For all of your conditions, you want to compare the column values with *parameter* values.  Like this:

```
category = :category
```

Repeat this for all of your parameters.

It also looks like you might be binding the `:id` parameter a bit differently, and I wonder if that's resulting in the errors you alluded to in a previous attempt to correct this code.  [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255657/pdo-prepared-statements-with-wildcards) may be helpful for binding wildcards in PDO parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the response David, That did  solve the problem but now its not outputting any result at all.

Comment: @MarkSmart: Seems reasonable that your `WHERE` clause might not be matching any records then.

Comment: I just the the result at the end which echo "no result found".