# How to use bindValue with LIKE operator in SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

I've been trying to replace the value in '%:value%' when I use the LIKE operator in my query.

I have also tried using CONCAT() but that didnt work either.

```
    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM books
              WHERE title LIKE '%:title%'";
    ...
    ...
    statement->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

:title should be replaced with the variable $title but it doesnt. The query is working fine but the :title just doesnt get replaced.

Comment: Use a ***literal*** `:title` placeholder and `->bindValue(':title', "%$title%"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want :

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM books
          WHERE title LIKE CONCAT( '%', :title, '%')";
...
...
statement->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The bind parameter should be used as a litteral  string. CONCAT can be used to concatenate the parameter with percent signs on both ends.

Comment: Thanks. I might have had a typo when I used CONCAT().

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `concat()` like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM books
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :title, '%')
```

Comment: Thanks. I might have had a typo when I used CONCAT().