# Get all values from SQL that contains certain value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all values from table products, that contains for example shirt. 
In this case $thin is getting values from searach box "stxt". 
It means that if $thin = shirt, I want to get shirt, t-shirt etc. 
 Right now, only thing that I get is only shirt, despite if I will use "LIKE" or "=" as operator in $sql statement.

```
$thin = $_POST['stxt'];
$thing = strtoupper($thin);
$sql = "select * from products where upper(productName) LIKE '$thing'";
```

Comment: `LIKE '%' || '$thing' || '%'`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 0):

In your query, put in your LIKE % before and after your variable.
Like this "%$variable%".
If you want there to be just a number of n characters before or after your variable, put the _ symbol n times.
And for security reasons, try to use prepared statements.

Link sql like: https://sql.sh/cours/where/like

Comment: You should not give an answer that includes a clear security risk.

Answer (score 0):

can you use a regexp operator ?

$sql = "select * from products where productName regexp $thing";

Answer (score -1):

```
$thin = $_POST['stxt'];
$thing = strtoupper($thin);
$sql = "select * from products where upper(productName) LIKE '%$thing%'";
```

MSSQL needs % wildcards, other SQL dialects may differ.
Alternatively you could do a REPLACE(productName,'$thing','') and compare the length of that to the original length.
Either way it is going to be a full table scan unless you have full text indexes set up.

Comment: You should not give an answer that includes a clear security risk.

Comment: the risk has already been pointed out be a previous commenter, but yes it is not a good idea, however because this is using a wildcard search you can't parameterise the query so it would have to be a stored procedure which is probably beyond the skills of the OP if they are asking this question.

Comment: But [you can parameterise a wildcard search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255657/pdo-prepared-statements-with-wildcards). Just bind to `"%$thing%"`. I'm sorry about repeating things...